# PowerShell executable not found when i'm running flutter commands

Tags: android, powershell, flutter

when running flutter command I'm getting this error.
Error: PowerShell executable not found. Either pwsh.exe or PowerShell.exe must be in your PATH.

I have tried installing Windows Management Framework 5.1 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616)

when installing Windows Management Framework 5.1 I'm getting this error.
Error: The update is not applicable to your computer.

[about my pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHoix.png)

any solution?

Comment: win10 already includes the WMF version you tried to install. [*grin*] that explains the error about that installation attempt. however, PoSh5.1 should have been available. this dir >>> `C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\` <<< is where PoSh gets  installed ... and it is there by default on win10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried installing Windows Management Framework 5.1 but it didn't work. It gave me an error - "this update not applicable to your computer" then I installed the latest stable version from GitHub and the setup automatically created the PowerShell path and solved my problem.

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/

**OR**
install the powershell from the Microsoft store